# Design of low current sensor from 50mA to 2A in a dc-dc buck converter

Tags: low-power, cadence, current-sensing

I would like to sense the current from a path where a current of 50mA to 2 A is flowing to the load. Can I use simple differential amp with gain across the Rsense =20mohm or is there any contemporary design help.
Output of a dc-dc buck converter with Vin =21V , Vout =10V C =15uF etc, Load is 6 ohm. I would like to measure the current for some decision making , mode change etc
thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [TI's product range for current sensing](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/amplifiers-linear/current-sense-amplifiers-overview.page?keyMatch=current%20shunt%20monitor&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything)? They have integrated solutions for measuring the high-side current. I was looking at them for measuring current through a motor, but haven't got to that project yet.

Comment: Definitely a good time to do some research to improve the specificity of your question.

Comment: Take a look at the hall-effect based sensors like Allegro ACS712 and closely related parts. Just another option.

Comment: This question feels a bit lacking in information. Please read the [help] to understand how you might improve it. Simple things to add to your question are: is it high-side current measurement or could it be in the ground-return path, is it a simple resistive load or something more complex like a motor and so (maybe) how frequently you need to measure current?

Comment: If Vout is 10V and load is 6 ohms then current = 1.66667 amps. Why do you need to measure it? Justification needed please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a small current-sense resistor to get a voltage proportional to current.

However, consider the competing tradeoffs.  You want this to drop as little voltage as possible to not effect the system being measure.  However, the lower the voltage, the smaller it is compared to the inevitable noise.  If you are measuring the current out of a 15 V unregulated supply, then 500 mV isn't going to matter much.  However, if you are measuring the current out of a 4 V battery, then even 100 mV drop can degrade performance or lifetime.

You can put the sense resistor in series with the current, then use a diff amp to get a ground-referenced voltage proportional to the current.  However, it's easier to use a chip specifically intended for high side current sensing.  Check out the INA139 and INA169 from Texas Instruments, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned if it's ac or dc current you are measuring. Take a look at the metrology section in this [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrfq8/tidrfq8.pdf). I built this and it works quite well. This senses ac current. The current is sensed by a 4m shunt which is then filtered and then fed into an instrumentation amp followed by a non inverting amp and then into an MCU adc.

Comment: Actually at the output of a dc-dc buck converter with Vin =21V , Vout =10V C =15uF etc, Load is 6 ohm. I would like to measure the current for some decision making , mode change etc.

Comment: Are you going to measure the current with an MCU or some other programmatic way? An integrated solution would be more useful than a single differential amp. The ACS712 or TI's INA219 seems like something that would get the job done.